# what is out parameter in c# and why we use it

Tags: c#

Why do we use ouput parameters, e.g.

```
void f() {
    int first, next;
    read(out first, out next);
}

void read (out int first, out intnext) {
    first = console.read();
    next = console.read();
}
```

Instead of writing all this code why don’t we use:

```
void f() {
    int first, next;
    first = console.read();
    next = console.read();
}
```

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366741/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[out (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx(VS.80).aspx)

[out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx(VS.71).aspx)

Declaring an out method is useful when you want a method to return multiple values. A method that uses an out parameter can still return a value. A method can have more than one out parameter.

The out keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference. This is similar to the ref keyword, except that ref requires that the variable be initialized before being passed. To use an out parameter, both the method definition and the calling method must explicitly use the out keyword.

Although variables passed as an out arguments need not be initialized prior to being passed, the calling method is required to assign a value before the method returns.

Answer (score 8):

An `out` parameter is very much like having an extra return value.

It's rarely a good idea to have an `out` parameter in a method which has a void return type, like the example you gave... but sometimes you want to be able to return multiple values at a time. Even in your example, you *might* want to encapsulate the "I'm reading from the console twice" idea in a single method call. It's somewhat unlikely in this case, because the operations are so easily separable - but in other cases, performing some work naturally gives two bits of information, and you don't want to have to repeat the work to get both bits. You could encapsulate them in a new struct or class, of course, but sometimes that's just a pain.

With .NET 4, it would often be a better idea to return a `Tuple<...>` instead, mind you. So whereas `int.TryParse` has a signature of

```
bool TryParse(string text, out int value)
```

it might have been better as

```
Tuple<bool, int> TryParse(string text)
```

Comment: Has this idea been discussed within Microsoft? I would love to see that `TryParse` overload in the next framework version :) (Bonus points if you can also write something like `(bool b, int i) = int.TryParse(str);`...

Comment: @Timwi: I've suggested that any method with `out` parameters should be usable as if it returns a tuple. Basically watch my video from NDC about what I'd like to see in C# 5 :) (streaming.ndc2010.no)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Since `Tuple` is a class, there is the minor disadvantage of allocating an object on the heap in the second version. Not that it should matter in most applications.

Comment: @Ani: Indeed... I'd rather have the extra readability. Of course, they could also create a `TupleStruct` set of types as the equivalent of `Tuple` but as structs.

Comment: @Roger: Yes, I should have mentioned that I entirely nicked this idea (and others) from F# :)

Comment: With the syntactic sugar now available for returning Tuples, I think this is an even more compelling solution today.

Answer (score 1):

`out` parameters effectively allow methods to have multiple return values. The modifier is not required for reference types, but for value types, changes you make to the parameter variables in the method body will not normally flow back to the calling code.